# How to add unit test for window keydown event in ReactJS with enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have the following code in my React component. On pressing escape key, unfocus prop function should be called. How do I test this? I am using jest and enzyme.

[image: reactjs enzyme test]

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more control over testing, I would recommend passing mousedown event logic as a prop function.

Then, after you mount component in your specs, you can test as --

```
test('should toggle focus', () => {
  const map = {};
  window.addEventListener = jest.genMockFn().mockImpl((event, cb) => {
    map[event] = cb;
  });

  const component = mount(<SomeComponent />);
  map.keyDown({ keyCode: 27 });
  expect(props.unfocus).to.have.been.called;
});
```

Useful links --

[Simulate KeyDown Event](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/441#issuecomment-224347241)

[Simulate Events on window](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/426#issuecomment-228601631)

Comment: but, window.simulate function wont be available as window is not a react component.